# It is legal and correct to create a new object within the class that I have created?

Tags: java, object

I have a homework assignment that requires me to implement a method within the object I created that returns an object of that type while the method has no parameters. The only way I could think of is to create an object of that class in the method by my question is that correct pattern design?
I mean it works but I don't know if its good implementation.

this is the method:

```
public Matrix flipHorizontal(){ }
```

So I have created a matrix object (with copy constructor) within this method which is part of Matrix class then I manipulated the matrix accordingly and then I returned the object.

Comment: Please provide your code here. Generally speaking, it is totally legal and correct to create a new object in a method in Java.

Comment: You may be speaking of the singleton pattern, look it up.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. It is a reasonable practice to have member functions of some class X return newly created instanced of X.

Especially when X is designed to be immutable, for example like BigDecimal. That class allows for mathematical computations of objects - but each instance can't be changed upon creation. Therefore there is no other ways as implementing `plus(BigDecimal other)` by returning a new BigDecimal that represents "this + other".

The only thing that does **not** work: creating another instance of X within constructor of X. That can easily lead to a never ending recursion. Which ends with stack overflow at some point, or maybe out of memory problems.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's perfectly fine. It's commonly used when objects are immutable. Such a method may return a copy of the object and apply some modification.

Take for example [`LocalDate.withYear`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#withYear-int-) which is an instance method which returns a new immutable `LocalDate`. Sample usage:

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2018, 1, 1);
LocalDate nextYear = date.withYear(2019);
```

We now have two distinct instances, one a year after the other.

It is not required that your object be immutable if you want to do this, though that might be where it's most commonly used. If your class is not immutable, you should probably note in your JavaDoc that the method returns a new instance rather than modifying the existing one in order to prevent any confusion.

---

Alternatively, another implementation that would match that signature would be to modify the current instance and then `return this`:

```
class Matrix {
    Matrix flipHorizontal() {
        //do the flip...
        return this;
    }
}
```

This would effectively be a kind of [fluent interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface). It may be desirable, but in your case I think it's probably not.